# adding element in array will not accept similar element

Tags: c++

im practicing adding elements in array and i did add a while loop to prevent adding if the array has already existing elements and must input a different character from the array. the problem is that in my example, i input a character 'a' and then 'b' after 'b' i tried to input 'a' again and it accepted the input. it supposed to be not to accept an already existing element and yet it did. why is that? thanks in advance

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char array[5] = {'a','a','a','b','b'};
    char add;

    for(int x = 0; x<5; x++){
            cout<<"[" <<array[x] <<"]";
        }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Add element: ";
    cin>>add;

        //if the element is already existing, prompt user to input again
        for(int x =0 ;x<5;x++){
            while(add==array[x]){
            cout<<"Already Exist and its in position " <<x+1 <<" Please add a different character:  ";
            cin>>add;
            }

        }

    array[5] = add; //adding the element in the last position

    //if adding succesfull, display the new element
    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"Adding Succesful! Your new array is" <<endl;

        for(int x = 0; x<=5; x++){
            cout<<"[" <<array[x] <<"]";
        }

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: `array[5] = add;` adds *past* the last element and therefore invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: You can't add elements to this type of array. Its size is fixed at compile time. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Also your `while` loop will only re-check the current element and the `for` loop will continue (not restart) afterwards

Comment: @UnholySheep i see, so the while loops should be outside the for loop?

Comment: @rustyx i already tried the if statement but its just that if the user insist of inputting already existing element i think while loop will prevent them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop. At first you enter 'a'. This causes the while loop to begin which then ends when you enter 'b'. At this stage you go out of the while loop and x = x+1 in the for loop. This time while loop is not used and x=x+1 again. When x=3, while loop is opened again because array element at location 3 is 'b'. When you enter 'a' after this the only element remaining inside the array is 'b'. So it does not go into the while loop. It instead goes out of all the loops and continues to run.

You could've found this error by dry running. Try correcting it yourself. Otherwise you can see my solution which works on the data that i tested it on.

**Solution:**

```
        for(int x =0 ;x<5;x++)
        {
            if (add==array[x])
            {
                cout<<"Already Exist and its in position " <<x+1 <<" Please add a different character:  ";
                cin>>add;

                x=-1; //So that char 'add' is compared again with each element of the array.
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `std::set` instead. It will only allows to insert an item once and the return value will allows you to know if an item was inserted or not;

```
std::set<char> characters;
char item = 'a'; // read it from input or whatever you want instead.
auto result = characters.insert(itemToInsert);
if (!result.second) { display error message }
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/

If you need to remember the insertion order, then you can use both a `std::set` an a `std::vector`. With the first one, it will be easy to find if an item was inserted.

Note that in some cases, you could simply do a linear search in a `std::vector` using `find()` member function. If the expected number of item is relatively small it might be in fact the best approach particularly if the data itself is a simple data type.

Answer (score 0):

You should to `x=0` in `while`. So

```
for(int x =0 ;x<5;x++){
            while(add==array[x]){
            cout<<"Already Exist and its in position " <<x+1 <<" Please add a different character:  ";
            cin>>add;
            x=0;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that nested loops is the most readable way to do it… Replacing `while` with `if` and `x=0` with `x = -1` would be much easier to understand. Even better would be to split the function in multiple functions with descriptive names.